# Nozzle vs Orifice Water Jug Draining

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

why is this happening?
[Water jug draining](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2E5Jzh35jw)

So why does the water drain faster when you drain a jug through a funnel compared to the hole you make at the bottom of a jug( the hole is the same size as the funnel one)?

[image]

Comment: We prefer questions to be self-contained such that the link isn't a complete necessity, so could you do more to explain the link? Perhaps include a screenshot?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry.So why does the water drain faster when you drain a jug through a funnel compared to the hole you make at the bottom of a jug( the hole is the same size as the funnel one)?

Comment: It'd be better to use the `edit` button to edit your comment into the question.

Comment: OK, I added the screenshot aswell.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "turbulence."  In the "funnel" scenario, the shape of the funnel is similar to the Laval nozzle of a rocket engine.  It's designed to allow the fluid to flow through the exit in smooth, efficient streamlines that don't interfere with each other.  In the case with the round hole cut in the bottom, the fluid molecules jostle around, have to change direction quickly, and bump into each other as they exit, thus expending some of their energy and slowing the flow.  Look up Laval nozzles and the history of rockets if you want a more detailed explanation.